# Joda DateTime gmt issue

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I wanted to raise issue directly on joda github, but there was a hint, that i should at first ask it on stackoverflow.

If you try to use joda DateTime object in Greenwich Mean Time Zone (UK), you are getting bad DateTime value

### Step to reproduce

Write method like this

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2014-02-16T07:00:00.000Z");
System.out.println(dt);
```

### Expected value

1. `2014-05-16T07:00:00.000+00:00`

### Actual value

1. `2014-05-16T07:00:00.000+Z`

In UK, time is changed every 29 March. This is the last day in year, when time is +00:00. From 30 march till next time change there is +01:00.

If think that joda has problem with processing +00:00 gmt.

Comment: Zulu/UTC/GMT time are not affected by daylight savings time. [Neither UTC nor GMT ever change for Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html)

Comment: Why do you escape the letter "Z" in your input? It means UTC+00:00, and the parser should automatically interprete it as UTC (ISO-8601-standard).

Answer (score 0):

***UK Time is not GMT***... If you want UK time, use a full timezone name: `Europe/London`.

Answer (score 0):

UK could be in GMT or BST based on the time of the year. The timezone can be mentioned like below:-

```
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("2014-02-16T07:00:00.000Z").withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London"));
```